# Anomalous magnetic moment, BMT equation, and Mathisson-Papapetrou-Dixon equations

Tags: special-relativity, magnetic-moment

It is my understanding that the Bargmann-Michel-Telegdi (BMT) equation [Phys. Rev. Lett. **2**, 435 (1959)] plays a central role in precision experiments measuring the anomalous magnetic moment of the muon or electron in order to look for physics beyond the standard model [e.g., Jegerlehner, The Anomalous Magnetic Moment of the Muon (Springer, 2017)].  I believe that the BMT equation is really equivalent to Frenkel's old theory on the electrodynamics of the rotating electron [Z. Phys. **37**, 243 (1926)].  The equations of motion derived by Frenkel and BMT involve what is sometimes called the Frenkel (-Mathisson) condition, that is, the orthogonality of spin angular momentum $S^{\mu\nu}$ and velocity $v_\mu$ of the system, $S^{\mu\nu} v_\mu = 0$ [Eq. (7a) = (18b) in Frenkel's paper; Eq. (2) in the BMT paper].  The same condition was used by Mathisson (and others) in a theory for the dynamics of rotating objects in the framework of general relativity [Mathisson, Acta Phys. Pol. **6**, 163 (1937); also Gen. Relat. Gravit. **42**, 1011 (2010)].  Later it was noted that Frenkel's and Mathisson's equations of motion are problematic because they are third-order differential equations [e.g., Weyssenhoff and Raabe, Acta Phys. Pol. **9**, 7 (1947); Dixon, Nuovo Cimento **34**, 317 (1964)].  Therefore, Tulczyjew [Acta Phys. Pol. **18**, 393 (1959)] and Dixon [loc. cit.; also Nuovo Cimento **38**, 1616 (1965)] suggested to replace the Frenkel condition $S^{\mu\nu} v_\mu = 0$ by what became known as Tulczyjew-Dixon condition $S^{\mu\nu} p_\mu = 0$, where $p_\mu$ is momentum.  I believe that these things are well-known in general relativity, where the equations of motion based on the Tulczyjew-Dixon condition are called Mathisson-Papapetrou-Dixon equations, see, e.g., Puetzfeld et al., Equations of Motion in Relativistic Gravity (Springer, 2015).

My question is: are these things also relevant for experiments such as those studying the anomalous magnetic moment of the muon or electron?  Should the interpretation of these precision experiments possibly use the Mathisson-Papapetrou-Dixon equations?  [It is my understanding that the difference between these models is not a matter of bringing general relativity into the discussion, as in the recent work by Laszlo and Zimboras, Class. Quantum Grav. **35**, 175003 (2018).  But the difference between the Frenkel condition and the Tulczyjew-Dixon condition becomes relevant already at the level of the special theory of relativity.]